How to Recover Bad Super Block? Write Lock Corrupted Nvme
This morning I had problems booting on my laptop. I force power cycled it and the disk was no longer detected. I booted to a live ubuntu drive to try and repair the disk.
This disk is a Samsung 1TB Nvme card. It has 3 partitions
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1050624 1945135103 1944084480  927G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1945135104 1953523711    8388608    4G Linux swap

I first tried to repair the boot partition nvme0n1p1 using fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p1 - walked through the prompts restoring the backup block and removing the dirty flag. After doing this I was able to mount the boot partition (although still not recognized by system)
I've now been exhaustively trying to recover the main partition /dev/nvme0n1p2 receiving various errors:
errors from gparted
Error fsyncing/closing /dev/nvme0n1p2: No data available

fsck
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2 
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Ubuntu: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while recovering journal of Ubuntu
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on Ubuntu


Ubuntu: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

Trying to restore from superblock backup. Tried every single one
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep -i superblock
dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-116
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32884
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98420
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163956
  ...
  ...
dumpe2fs: Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap while trying to read '/dev/nvme0n1p2' bitmaps

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n1p2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
Ubuntu: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of Ubuntu
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on Ubuntu


Ubuntu: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

Ubuntu: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

Running badblocks gives me 1500+ bad blocks. I stopped it short. But maybe I should try repairing these blocks?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo badblocks -c 4096 /dev/nvme0n1p2 > /home/$USER/badblocks.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wc -l /home/$USER/badblocks.txt
1325 /home/ubuntu/badblocks.txt

Tried to mount a superblock directly
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -o sb=32768 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/backupSuperblock
mount: /mnt/backupSuperblock: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Trying to check sector alignment with gparted. Shows it's fine but I'm not confident since it's having IO issues.
root@ubuntu:~# parted /dev/nvme0n1p2
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/nvme0n1p2: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? Ignore                                                      
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/nvme0n1p2
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) align-check opt 1
1 aligned

There is no physical write write lock switch on the card I checked. I also tried a different nvme storage card in the same interface and it works fine.
I've exhausted everything I can think of trying to find clues. I was able to recover the other 2 partitions which makes me feel like the card is not damaged physically beyond repair and is capable of io. I'm really hoping I can recover this one at least to the extent that I'm able to mount it and recover some work.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to repair this corrupted partition?

In case this helps anyone. It doesn't appear there is a way to recover the superblock if all backups are also corrupt. You can still mount the used parts of the disk to recover data if you know the offsets.
A different ubuntu forum pointed me toward testdisk. I was able to recover the data off of the disk using this utility.
